# mvn archetype:generate failed (maven 3.6.3)

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

when I run `mvn archetype:generate` an error causes the failling:

```
    C:\demo\New processor>mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/utils/cli/CommandLineException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.411 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T18:42:37+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate: org/apache/maven/shared/utils/cli/CommandLineException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/3.1.2/maven-archetype-plugin-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/3.1.2/archetype-catalog-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/3.1.2/archetype-descriptor-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/3.1.2/archetype-common-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.16/groovy-2.4.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.0/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/3.0.1/maven-invoker-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.11.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/eya/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

knowing that I'm using maven3.6.3 / java 8 (jdk1.8_181) / windows10

Comment: Do you have an environment variable like `M2_HOME` or `MAVEN_HOME` or duplicate maven versions on your path?

Comment: @khmarbaise I solved it !!!! I deleted C:/Users/eya/.m and I rerun `mvn archetype:generate` and alll worked like magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to delete : `C:/Users/~~(local user folder : in my case called "eya")/.m2` and all will works like magic